Drawing a cubic Bezier curve from four points along the curve
I have a function that will return any point(x,y) along a curve from its start point to its end point: getPointOnCurve(t), where t is a number from 0–1, 0 being the point at the start of the curve, 1 being the end of the curve and the values between 0 and 1 being points in between.
I need to draw a cubic Bezier curve that describes this curve. I have access to the start and end points, however I don't have access to the two control points, so I need a way to calculate those.
Given that I know the start and end points, and can provide any point along the curve, along with the point's distance along the curve, is it possible to calculate the two control points?
I know that if only four points are available (without the distances for those points) that there a multiple possible solutions, but if the distances are available, I can't find a definitive answer on whether creating an accurate curve is possible, and if it is, how accurate it might be.
Please assume that the curve can be described by a cubic Bezier curve.

Did you look at CR, I know it's not a bezier but it did a great jo for us for smoothing the curve: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centripetal_Catmull%E2%80%93Rom_spline

Have a look at https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#curvefitting, and the now webarchived https://web.archive.org/web/20180403213813/http://jimherold.com/2012/04/20/least-squares-bezier-fit/ it was based on. Having just four points is not enough to find "the" Bezier curve through them, because there are infinitely many, so you'll need clamp the "t" values for your control points in some way that makes sense. You can either go with 1/2 and 2/3, or you can calculate the t value as a ratio of chord distance.

@JsCoder thanks. Yeah I did look at CR, but ultimately I need to be able output this to SVG and CR isn't supported (and I didn't fancy another step of conversion from CR to Bezier).

Note that the conversion from CR (though technically, cardinal spline; no one really knows what a Catmull-Rom curve is supposed to be, we all just made up our own definition =D) is incredibly simple though. It's just a straight up value transform. The real issue is having to come up with virtual start and end points, which makes CR way less useful than direct polynomial fitting.

On that note: do you only have access to the distance for a sampled point, or do you have access to the "t" value? Because if it's the latter, then doing what you need is pretty easy. If it's distance, then you still have a problem because Bezier curves are non-linear curves wrt distance.

But how does your function calculates points at t without knowing the bezier control points? What are the inputs/parameters? It would be helpful to see a JS example of this function

There's a "view source" link right there on the example graphic. As for how it calculates "t" values: it doesn't, that's still up to you (hence the sliders). If you only have distance, then there is literally no symbolic answer: you'd have to reparameterize the Bezier curve to be linear wrt distance, which is a famously impossible task. What you can do is start with a best guess of t values, and then iterate on those by comparing the distances and then redoing your attempt with updated t values until you've converged on an acceptable approximation.

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans thanks very much. I'd completely missed that. I've swapped your implementation in and it's greatly improved. Still struggles when the curve is tight around the start or end point, but much much better than what I had before: It's here if you're interested: https://coons-patch.undistraction.com/ Only noticable when the grid is set to very low values 2 or 3 rows or columns.

oh, that looks very nice!

Thanks. The idea is to use a coons patch for generating grids for design. I've got the interpolation working between the four curves, but drawing the grid itself it the hard part. I can interpolate a point anywhere in the surface, which means I can interpolate the points along the curves that make the gird lines, but I then need to get from the points to curves. I want this to be able to output to SVG for print, so I can't really get away with cheating and drawing straight lines between lots of points.

@herrstrietzel I've incorporated Pomax's code into the package and you can see that here ig you are interested: https://github.com/Undistraction/coons-patch. T values are generated using a coons patch which can provide X and Y t-values interpolated between four cubic Bezier curves. I'll add an answer with the code once I've cleaned it up a little more. The piece I was missing was turning the t-values that make up a curve into a Bezier curve. The curve fitting is not perfect but it's a great improvement on what I had before.

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans fyi I've added a credit to you I'm the files that use your fitting code and replaced the third-party dependency with a different package. I've also added a thanks to the README.
